# How to get specific items using index numbers from SimpleCursorAdapter in android

Tags: android, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter, mediastore

I want to filter out some of specific items from my List View resource (SimpleCursorAdapter fetched all audio files on Android device).

**Adapter class:** It returns a view for List View item.

```
    public class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

            public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
                super(context, layout, c,
                        new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION, MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM_ID},
                        new int[]{R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration, R.id.single_album_art});
            }
    }

public MediaCursorAdapter rootMediaCursorAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, gCursor);
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) rootMediaCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
    String songData = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
```

here, songData contains the item of 'position' index from adapter. Suppose I've some indexes and I want to get some filtered items in a list so that I can generate a filtered List View. If you please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: see `setFilterQueryProvider()`

Comment: #pskink, I mentioned, I've just index values. If you please give me an example using index list (suppose: 4, 6, 9, 11, 15 totaled of 5 items from 50 items in main cursorAdapter). Thanks.

Comment: you dont need any index values, how do you want to filter your listview? based on what? display name? title? both?

Comment: Suppose, based on title... then???

Comment: then add a `TextWatcher` to some `EditText` or when using `SearchView` add `OnQueryTextListener` and simply call `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` inside the listenter

Comment: I didn't make you understood or you didn't get my point. SearchView already implemented and working fine using OnQueryTextListener. I'm making you sure again that I wanna generate a curstomSongList from the mainList where I do have those item's index values. Do you get my point now??

Comment: ok so what do you call inside `OnQueryTextListener#onQueryTextChange(String newText)` ? do you call  `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)` ?

Comment: inside #onQueryTextSubmit(String query), I generated a List<Integer> based on (query=title/artist) condition which denotes item's index. And using those indexes, I completed the new list view.

Comment: again no need for any indexes, just run [those](https://pastebin.com/i1KYR0V1) twenty-something lines of code and you will know how it works

Comment: Hey... thanks. I'm leaving my workstation because this is end of the day. I'll check it later and make you informed.

Comment: Hey, I'm on some other works till now. I'm gonna catch your example in a while.

Comment: Thanks man... I got at least the usage of setFilterQueryProvider() method :)

Comment: good, now you can remove your indexes

Comment: Do you have sense on how could I create a playlist for my musicplayer and save the list for future listening??

Comment: use `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists` which i didnt know about until now

Comment: You spent huge time... let me try the last option you suggested "MediaStore.Audio.Playlists" and I hope, it'll work for me. Thanks